# Spyro Year of the Dragon complete but only 91% - what am I missing?

Tags: spyro-year-of-the-dragon, spyro-reignited-trilogy

I have all levels 100%, a few levels over 100%. I have 13814 gems and 140 eggs. But my game total is only 91%?

I have gone through the guidebook over and over, I can't seem to find the rest of what I'm missing.